# do all type of sql server license have SA account?

Tags: sql, licensing

We are trying to upgrade our sql server from 2005 to 2012. we got some offers for different type of license from some resellers. the only thing I'm not sure now is, there's one type core license **with software assurance** (more expensive), and another type core license **without software assurance** (cheaper). I wonder if this software assurance means the access of **SA account**?

we would of course like to have the SA access, as we have now in sql 2005.

I guess i'm probably confused with the meaning of software assurance and SA account.

---

*This question is not a double to the suggested question, I was confused with the SA account, and the Software assurance in SQL server license. It's completely two different questions, and the answer from the other post, doesn't answer my question.*

Comment: SA like the SA user, that is totally absolutely not related to licensing but the traditional "administrator" account that goes back to Sybase Sql Server times? If you mean the sql user sa then man, you really have a mixup between license (legal) and technical implementation details. If not, then this question makes zero sense.

Comment: @TheCleaner Absolutely NOT a doule as it is not even a licensing question (as legal) but a simply mixup by a user account using the same abbrevation than a license extension. Please at least read a question (and comments / answers) and what we do not like about licensing issues..... this is not even a licensing issue.

Comment: I did read it...but I'm not going to VTC it as "derp"...I upvoted your answer as the right answer...but the question itself...ummm...and you could venture: `Am I entitled to feature X with license Y?` on that canonical relates to here...even if the OP was simply confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SA accout in SQL server is the traditional "System Administrator" and goes back to the time that was a Sybase product. It has zero relationship with Software Assurance or any licensing. It is just a standard account that is created so that one CAN (it can be disabled at install time or later) log in as a local machine administrator FOR THE DATABASE SERVER without bothering with a windows password.

Totally unrelated to licensing and available in all versions of the software.

Comment: ah.. I thought the same, I was completely confused with SA user and licensing with Software assurance, which is also called SA. Thanks for your reply ;). problem solved..